# EmberCLI server not working ( no browser response, no errors )

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, ember-cli

Title says about it all, I installed the ember CLI, changed `ember` and `ember-data` to version `2` in `bower.json`, and everything installed well. Now as i understand it, there should be at least *something* by default when i start the `ember server`. But my browser goes into an endles loading loop when i visit `localhost:4200`. here is the response from `ember server`:

```
C:\Users\Tobias\Documents\ARTII-Ember>ember server
Future versions of Ember CLI will not support v4.1.2. Please update to  Node 0.12 or io.js.
version: 1.13.8
Livereload server on http://localhost:49152
Serving on http://localhost:4200/
```

Yes, I'm using windows, don't ask me why. But does anyone know what the problem here is?

Comment: Have you tried to update your node version? What version are you currently using?

Comment: @DoryZidon as the error message says, Im using `v4.1.2`,which, as i understand it, is a higher version than `0.12`

Comment: What console errors appear in the browser, if any?

Comment: none, it loads forever

Comment: Running as admin? The Ember CLI server is really slow when on Windows in non-admin mode.

Comment: it might be, but its not 20-minutes slow

Answer (score 2):

Using an elevated prompt helped me. For anyone else, right click the start icon and choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`. It didn't load for me at all, and now it does. Thanks @elithrar

Comment: Elevated rights also allows ember/npm to create links instead of copying  everything back and forth thus dramatically decreasing startup time and size.